# C# Javascript Beautifier

Tags: c#, javascript

I am wondering if anyone knows of an open source c# library for beautifying javascript. I would like to make use of such a library within my asp net website to make debugging messy javascript easier.

There are currently many online websites for this (ie. http://jsbeautifier.org/) however I would like to have access to such a utility within c#, even if it is just a wrapper for communicating with an online API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The site you pointed out suggests a command line tool. Wouldn't it be enough for you?

> To beautify from the command-line you
>   can use provided beautify-cl.js
>   script, using [Rhino javascript engine](http://www.mozilla.org/rhino/).
>   See the file contents for the details.

Comment: Problem Solved! I just downloaded the package from github and there is a c-sharp folder which contains a port in JSBeautify.cs :-D

Comment: Great news, maybe that will come in useful for me as well in the future. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: http://github.com/einars/js-beautify/blob/master/unmaintained/c-sharp/JSBeautify.cs

Answer (score 6):

You can use jsbeautifylib.

http://jsbeautifylib.codeplex.com/

It's the file/folder you found :)

Also there is a C# port of [js-beautify](https://github.com/beautify-web/js-beautify) by Denis Ivanov [here](https://github.com/denis-ivanov/Jsbeautifier)

And in the simplest of form, there is [JSBeautify.cs](https://github.com/kriskowal/montage-simple-flow/blob/master/node_modules/montage-testing/support/js-beautify/attic/unmaintained/c-sharp/JSBeautify.cs)